# Echo php Variable in script

Tags: javascript, php

having problem to echo this...

```
$order_id = $order->get_order_number();
$order_totals = $order->get_formatted_order_total();
```

...in a script from an affiliate site. I have tried different ways to echo this above values in my php file but nothing workt.

Here is the script form the Affiliate site.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.adcell.de/js/track.js?eventid=xxx&pid=yyy&referenz=AAAA&betrag=111.11"></script>
<noscript>
    <img src="//www.adcell.de/event.php?pid=xxx&eventid=yyy&referenz=AAAA&betrag=111.11" border="0" width="1" height="1">
</noscript>
```

referenz=AAAA must output value $order_id

betrag=111.11 must output value $order_totals

Comment: referenz = `<? echo $order_id ?>`

Comment: Thanks for Help, but i tryed now and its not working. Value is Blank.

Answer (score -1):

Php Will execute before javascript so you can use directly .

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.adcell.de/js/track.js?eventid=xxx&pid=yyy&referenz=AAAA&betrag=111.11"></script>
    <noscript>
        <img src="//www.adcell.de/event.php?pid=xxx&eventid=yyy&referenz=<?php echo $order_id;?>&betrag=<?php echo $order_totals;?>" border="0" width="1" height="1">
    </noscript>
```

Comment: Thank you also blank with this try.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.adcell.de/js/track.js?eventid=xxx&pid=yyy&referenz=<?php echo $order_id; ?>&betrag=<?php echo $order_totals; ?>"></script>
<noscript>
     <img src="//www.adcell.de/event.php?pid=xxx&eventid=yyy&referenz=<?php echo $order_id; ?>&betrag=<?php echo $order_totals; ?>" border="0" width="1" height="1">
</noscript>
```

This will work.

Comment: Also no data in output. All scripts worked but data output still blank. $order_id & $order_totals are the correct values and the script works with only Text input...but the php output is blank.

Comment: trying 3 days right now. This is driving me crasy. Hope anyone has a another idea.

Comment: Did you try to echo in plain php file those variables?

Answer (score -1):

you must try this:-

```
echo "referenz=".$order_id ;
echo "betrag=".$order_totals;
```

ask if there is any problem again.. thanks

Comment: Try this: 
echo $_post['order_id'];
echo $_post['order_totals'];